# Disappearing Picturebox images

Tags: vb.net, image

I was successful in loading an image from a file into a picturebox in visual basic.  Or so i thought.  I had a msgbox in the code and the picture showed up in the picturebox.  take the msgbox out and no picture. Any Ideas? Thanks

```
    Private Sub DrawImageinSquarePanel(Panelname As PictureBox, ImageFile As String)
    g = Panelname.CreateGraphics() 'creates new graphics element in panel
    Dim newImage As Image = Image.FromFile(ImageFile) ' Create image.
    Dim SquareDim As Integer 'Size of longest dimension in source image

    If newImage.Width > newImage.Height Then
        SquareDim = newImage.Width
    Else
        SquareDim = newImage.Height
    End If

    MsgBox(Panelname.Width & "   " & Panelname.Height) 'the magic msgbox!!

    ' scale factor
    Dim imageAttr As New ImageAttributes
    imageAttr.SetGamma(Panelname.Width / SquareDim)
    Dim ScaleFactor As Single = Panelname.Width / SquareDim

    ' Create rectangle for source and destination image.
    Dim srcRect As New Rectangle(0, 0, newImage.Width, newImage.Height)
    Dim destRect As New Rectangle((Panelname.Width - newImage.Width * ScaleFactor) / 2, (Panelname.Height - newImage.Height * ScaleFactor) / 2, newImage.Width * ScaleFactor, newImage.Height * ScaleFactor)
    Dim units As GraphicsUnit = GraphicsUnit.Pixel

    ' Draw image to screen.
    g.DrawImage(newImage, destRect, srcRect, units)


End Sub
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your title says "Picturebox" but there's no `PictureBox` there at all.  If you want to display an `Image` in a `PictureBox` then assign the `Image` object to the `Image` property of that `PictureBox`.

Don't use GDI+ to draw it on a `Panel` and, if you ever do use GDI+ to draw, **NEVER** call `CreateGraphics`.  Always draw on a control in its `Paint` event handler.  The reason that your drawing disappears is that all drawing is erased on every `Paint` event.  By doing your drawing in the `Paint` event handler, you ensure that it gets reinstated each time.

If you want to modify the image before displaying it then what you should do is create a new `Bitmap` object, use GDI+ to draw the modified image onto that and then assign that to the `Image` property of the `PictureBox`, e.g.

```
Using originalImage = Image.FromFile(filePath)
    Dim newImage As New Bitmap(originalImage.Width, originalImage.Height)

    Using g = Graphics.FromImage(newImage)
        g.DrawImage(originalImage, Point.Empty)
    End Using

    'Dispose the existing image if there is one.
    PictureBox1.Image?.Dispose()

    PictureBox1.Image = newImage
End Using
```

Comment: jmcilhinney, Thank you very much for the help.  The project was pulled together very nicely following your suggestion.

Comment: If this answer has solved your issue, please accept it so that everyone can see that.